# ComboBox binding issues with custom class

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am having issues with my combo box. I am trying to set the selection at runtime, but the binding is not working.

```
public ICLINKDesignatorCandidate SelectedDesignator
  SelectedDesignator.Designator = somevalue;
...
<ComboBox Grid.Row="4" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"  
          SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=DesignatorId}"  
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDesignator}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding DesignatorList}"  />
```

So I am getting a binding error:

> BindingExpression path error: 'DesignatorId' property not found on 'object' ''TCard4312VM' (HashCode=47413204)'. BindingExpression:Path=DesignatorId; DataItem='TCard4312VM' (HashCode=47413204); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedValuePath' (type 'String')

**So WHY is it looking at the parent view model instead of the CLINKDesignatorCandidate object?**

So the SelectedValuePath is looking at the parent view model INSTEAD of the property on an element in the DesignatorList. **The weird thing is, when my DesignatorList was a list of type "DESIGNATOR"(which was an entity framework entity), this worked perfectly fine, and there was no binding issues.**

DisplayName is obviously working properly, so I don't know why DesignatorID isn't. Here is the class:

```
public class CLINKDesignatorCandidate : ICLINKDesignatorCandidate
{
    public CLINKDesignatorCandidate()
    {

    }

    public int DesignatorID { get; set; }
    public DESIGNATOR Designator
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string DisplayName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


}
```

Here is the code that USED to work when I was binding to a list of type DESIGNATOR(entity framework entity):

```
  <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" IsEditable="True" 
            DisplayMemberPath="DesignatorName"  
            SelectedValuePath="{Binding Id}"  
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDesignator}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding DesignatorList}"  />
```

This worked perfectly fine and I never had any binding issues where it tried to look for "Id" in the parent view model.

I am setting the view model in code behind as follows:

```
    public New4312(IEquipment4312VM vm)
        : this()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = vm;
    }
```

I am using a DataTemplate in a resource dictionary for the combo box:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="resTCard4312MIP">
    <Button Tag="{Binding}" >

        <Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
            <telerik:Tile Width="100" Background="Purple">                    
                    <ComboBox Grid.Row="4"  IsEditable="True"  
                              DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"  
                              SelectedValuePath="{Binding Path=DesignatorId}"  
                              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedDesignator.DesignatorID}"  
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDesignator}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding DesignatorList}"  />
                </Grid>
            </telerik:Tile>
etc...
```

**Keep in mind all of this code worked when my DesignatorList was a list of entites instead of a custom class.**

Thanks for any assistance. I hope I have explained the issue well enough.

Comment: Format your questions.

Comment: What did I format improperly?

Comment: Did you see all the edits?  Empty lines?  Stuff off screen.

Comment: Interesting, it looks fine to me. Nothing is off screen.

Comment: Yes because it has been edited by others.  Go back to your original.  And it still has empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

DesignatorId

is not the same as

DesignatorID

Property names are case sensitive
The XAML does not match the property name

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedValuePath` is meant to be a string property that is used to identify the property name of the items to use as the Value. I think it's used by reflection internally, but am not sure.

Right now, you are binding that property to a property on your `ComboBox.DataContext`, and it sounds like your binding error is actually correct : There is no property named `DesignatorId` on your `ComboBox.DataContext` item, which is of type `TCard4312VM`

Change it from a binding to a string, and it should work

```
SelectedValuePath="DesignatorID"
```

As for why your selection isn't working correctly, there could be a few causes for that.

- One common one I see is that WPF can get confused when you bind more than one of the `Selected` properties (`SelectedItem`, `SelectedValue`, and `SelectedIndex`). All 3 properties set the exact same thing, which item is selected, however I believe there's no specific order they run in, and setting more than one can cause problems.

  Since you are binding to a custom object, I'd suggest removing the `SelectedItem` property, and only keeping the `SelectedValue` and the (corrected) `SelectedValuePath` properties.
- The second common reason a custom item does not get selected is because WPF compares the `SelectedItem` with the items in the `ItemsSource` using `.Equals`, which by default compares objects *by reference*. So if your `SelectedItem` is the exact same reference as an item in the `ItemsSource` it would work, however if it's not than it will think the item is not found and and no item will get selected.

  The common solution for this case is to either use `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath` for setting the selected item, or to override the `.Equals()` and `.GetHashCode()` of your item so the two are considered equal based on their data, not their reference.
- And the third thing I can think of that could be causing this is I don't see any change notification in your code. It could be that you left it out for simplicity, however I will often see new WPF users forgetting to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), so I figured it was worth mentioning. The PropertyChange notification is responsible for alerting the UI when a value has changed so it can refresh any bindings to that property.

Answer (score -1):

> So WHY is it looking at the parent view model instead of the CLINKDesignatorCandidate object?

Because that is what happens if you set a binding like this, only the result (value path) will be evaluated against the items, not the binding on path properties.

> The weird thing is, when my DesignatorList was a list of type "DESIGNATOR"(which was an entity framework entity), this worked perfectly fine, and there was no binding issues.

Somehow i don't believe you. The items source should have no influence on the fundamental mechanics of how the binding system works.